# How to impose Neumann boundary conditions describing quantum Hall effect?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

I am trying to solve the following differential equation :
$$
\nabla\cdot\left(\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 & c_2 \\ -c_2 & c_1
\end{pmatrix}\nabla\phi\right) = 0
$$
on a rectangular domain [1,0]x[0,1] with $c_2$ and $c_1$ constant, and $c_2/c_1\gg 1$.

The boundary conditions are $\phi = \pm 1$ on $x=1$ and $x=0$ respectively, and $n\cdot\left(\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 & c_2 \\ -c_2 & c_1
\end{pmatrix}\nabla\phi\right) = 0$ on $y = 0$ and $y=1$.

Here's my confusion :

Since c-matrix is constant, this will evaluate to the Laplace equation, and the Neumann boundary condition will become $\partial_y \phi = 0$, and the information about $c_2$ much larger than $c_1$ is lost, and as expected the contour plot looks like :

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 
     NeumannValue[0, y == 0] + NeumannValue[0, y == 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -1, x == 0]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ 
    ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]];

ContourPlot[u[x, y] /. sol1, {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

[image]

But if I set up the equation with a c-matrix then the equipotential lines look strange:

Edit: I forgot to say what `omegatimestau` is, it’s a function that is proportional to B, in the code snippet below it’s ~ 100, but I get the scratchy lines on the left and right sides of the box even if B = 0.

```
eqn = Inactive[
     Div][{{1, -omegactimestau[B]}, {omegactimestau[B], 1}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0;
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqn == 
    NeumannValue[0, y == 0] + NeumannValue[0, y == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 1, x == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == -1, x == 0]}, 
  phi, {x, y} ∈ 
   ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]]
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

So, I have two questions :

1. How do I set up the problem so that information in the constant c-matrix is not lost?
2. What is the strange behavior happening in the second case?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: What's the definition of `omegactimestau[B]`?

Comment: @xzczd omegatimes[B] is a function linear in B it’s a constant in the above operator definition. Sorry  I didn’t specify this in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all there's a simple mistake in your code, you've included `==` in the PDE twice! (Once when defining `eqn`, next inside `NDSolve`. ) Removing the redundant `==` results in a reasonable result. Still, it's slightly scratchy at the boundary, so let's make the grid denser:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
omegactimestau[B] = 100;
eqn = Inactive[Div][{{1, -omegactimestau[B]}, {omegactimestau[B], 1}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0;
reg = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}], 
                    MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> 10^-3];

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn, phi[1, y] == 1, phi[0, y] == -1}, 
                    phi, {x, y} ∈ reg];   

ContourPlot[sol1[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've omitted the zero `NeumannValue`s, because this is the default setting of `FiniteElement` method.

Comment: @xzcd Thank you for this answer, I don't understand the pdetoae function very well in the linked answer above, I have two doubts: 1) If I run the above code, it gives me error/warning ? saying 'Part 1 of {}' does not exist and 'Symbol called with 0 arguments'. 2) Do you know how I should go about solving such a differential equation because this is a well defined problem in the physical sense, by that I mean the boundary conditions have physical meaning of a constant voltage on the left and right sides of the box and current is zero on the top and bottom, and the c-matrix is conductivity.

Comment: @Shubham 1. Have you executed the whole definition of `pdetoae`? Notice you need to execute the whole code snippet in the link. 2. If this is a well-studied problem, can you add a reference?

Comment: @xzcd yes, I executed the code snippet in the link of the definition of pdetoae. The problem is well studied because the off-diagonal elements in the c-matrix are the conductivity for when voltage is applied in say, x and current is measured in y which is the Quantum Hall effect. Here's a reference, https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.47.15727.

Comment: @Shubham Then I guess you don't execute definition of `eqn`. My `eqn` is the same as yours so it's omitted in the answer.

Comment: @xzcd yup, it works. I think there were some conflicts in the code which gave those errors (because I had executed everything before). Anyways, thanks again for pointing out pdetoae, and the answer, as a newbie I am learning a lot. Do you have any advice for solving the pde in my question,  physically it means that current goes from right to left and because the off-diagonal is large the current wants to travel along the edges.

Comment: @Shubham Perhaps I'm too tired… I didn't notice there's a simple mistake. See my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134455/discussion-between-shubham-and-xzczd).